# Can there be a method for achieving reputation in chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, chat

I, and many others, spend a lot of time answering questions in the chat.

This however doesn't get reflected on our reputation on the main site.

Can there be method for awarding reputation in the chat ?

Comment: Do you mean like ask a question in chat room, which is answer by another user, so the user who answers it get some reputation.

Comment: Yeah sort of. So if someone asks a question in chat i feel there needs to be a method to mark as a question and then a reply to be marked as an answer. On Answering some reputation could be awarded for the helpful reply. I spend most days in chat and answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Seems a fair idea to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I, and many others, spend a lot of time answering questions in the chat

Unfortunately that's oftentimes counterproductive.

If it is a question that's reasonably fitting for the main site, that's where it should be asked. That way, a) it also helps *other* people with the same problem, instead of being buried in a chat transcript, b) it discourages the laziness of those people who don't care to do the minimum amount of work to phrase a useful question, and c) guess what – **you can get reputation** for answering it!

If it's *not* a question that fits on the main site, then why should you gain reputation by answering it?

Comment: Yeah and it would also take rep away from people like balpha

Comment: I do agree, i hadn't fully considered how it would detract from the main site's functionality.

Comment: the question could be too long winded to put on the main site but could be explained in chat. It may not be able to help other at all but would still be worth answering. Just nice to get a little something back from chat users.

Answer (score 2):

No. SE is Q&A site where users ask and answer the questions. Chat is a feature to discuss our issues in details. If user has any question which is fit to the FAQ of particular site, he can ask it directly on the site. Chat is localized because not all users use chat and not all users enter in the same chat room.

Comment: But sometimes questions and descriptions are so lengthy that it becomes difficult to articulate and long question loses attention, IMO.

Comment: @rohan-patel - If lengthy question fits on the main site then you should ask there, not in the chat. If it doesn't fit in the main site then [why should you gain reputation by answering it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177876/187824)

Comment: @hims056 because you are answering it... Just because it might not be worthy of the main site doesnt mean that question is not worth asking or answering. Would just be nice to get rep for your work.